# Cannot access the excel file which is not used

Tags: c#, excel

Im getting this Error Message

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Microsoft Excel cannot access the file '\\<NetworkPath>\<excelName>.xls'. There are several possible reasons:

• The file name or path does not exist.
• The file is being used by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
```

The need of using Interop is that i have web page which is compatible with excel (.XLHTML)
And i need to convert that file to .XLSX because i want read that file and work with the informations inside.

So i found a way to do it and wrote an procedure

```
static string ConvertExcelToXlsx(string excelFilePath, string tempDir)
{
    // get new extension
    string xlsxFilePath = tempDir + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFilePath) + ".xlsx";

    /* delete temporary excel if exists */
    File.Delete(xlsxFilePath);

    // save original .XLHTML to new .XLSX format
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = false;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook eWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    eWorkbook.SaveAs(xlsxFilePath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    eWorkbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    // return file path to new .XLSX file
    return xlsxFilePath;
}
```

In my testing, on my Local PC and on Server it was working fine, but now it does not and im getting the error message above.

I tried to run program from sysinternals to find if the file is being used by another process http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx

Handle.exe originalExcel.xls (extension is .xls but in fact its .xlhtml)

but it says its not used by another process and filePath is correct. So last bullet from error message is `The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.`
"
But on desktop there are no open excel files and in TASK MANAGER i dont see excel processes either. So what could be a problem and how can i solve this ?

Thank you

PS: All systems are Windows 7 with Excel installed.

Answer (score -1):

I think that file could be locked by your own process.
There is also an issue or leak in the following line
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook eWorkbook = excelApp**.**Workbooks**.**Open(excelFilePath,

The .. (two dots issue) will cause a leak. You might see one excel.exe running for each instance of excel app creation.